# How to make Visual Studio Code to parse inactive code also?

Tags: parsing, visual-studio-code

I need to emphasize that I want to know how to 'parse' the inactive code, not 'undimming' it.
Scenario : I am using VSCODE to create a project out of a codebase which will have platform based code and multiple such platform based folders. So each macro might be defined at multiple places. So VSCODE is not parsing the code protected by such macros.
For example

## if (MACRO == ENABLED)

```
CODE
```

## endif

The 'MACRO' is defined at multiple places because of the platform variations.
One more thing. Sometimes this MACRO might be defined during compile time using SCONS. Hence VSCODE is unable to find it's definition at all and is not parsing the code protected by it and treating it as inactive code.
I am using paid IDEs like Source Insight and really want to move to Visual Studio Code at work. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Accidentally I found an option in Visual code studio today.
Go to Command Palette (Ctrl+P) and type '>Toggle Intellisense Engine Fallback on Include Errors' and press Enter.
The required purpose of my question is served through this option.
I am not sure whether this is included in a recent update or I have missed this earlier. But I have searched the internet extensively for this in vain.
Apologies to those who has spent any time on my question.
Thank you,
Sriram Dinesh